# Native embedding: not finding UIKit in global namespace, for Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Ok I am getting a build error in an auto generated file.  The file is shown in the error statement at bottom.

I added using statements to see if the red squiggly under UIKit would go away but it hasn't.

```
#if __IOS__
    using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
    using UIKit;
    #elif __ANDROID__
    using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
    using Android.Graphics;
    using Android.Widget;

    #endif
```

**This is in the auto generate file where the error is occurring for UIKit:**

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "0.0.0.0")]
        private global::UIKit.UIPickerView iOSColumnScroller;
```

**Error:**
"Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0400 The type or namespace name 'UIKit' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?) **This is the auto generated file:** Y:....RiskMobileCross.MainView.xaml.g.cs"

I followed several tutorials to try to get this correct.  Any ideas on why my using references may not be working?  If it is as simple as missing an assembly reference I am confused on what I would be missing here.  If I were to reference my AppName.iOS project I get a circular reference error.

**Here is my XAML:**

```
xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:UIKit;assembly=Xamarin.iOS;targetPlatform=iOS"
.
.
.
<ios:UIPickerView 
     x:Name="iOSColumnScroller"

                        />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove x:Name="iOSColumnScroller"

Note that naming a native view with x:Name is not possible in either a Portable Class Library (PCL) project or a Shared Asset Project (SAP). Doing so will generate a variable of the native type, which will cause a compilation error. However, native views can be wrapped in ContentView instances and retrieved in the code-behind file, provided that a SAP is being used. For more information, see Referring to a Native View from Code.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/native-views/

Comment: I ended up not using native embedding because this was a month ago.  But if I go back to it, which is likely, I will use this method.